# Measure of preimage of nullset under a finite-to-one smooth function is nullset

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How can I show rigorously the following which is intuitively clear: Given a smooth function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is finite-to-one(or which satisfy some other from of 'weak injectivity') and a set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R$ of Lebesgue measure zero, then $f^{-1}(\Omega)$ also has measure zero.

Edit: For continuous functions, as i asked before, it is not true.

Comment: First, try to prove it for the case where $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism, and $\Omega$ is the Cantor set.

Comment: do you want to imply that it is in general wrong? If my function $f$ is smooth, then it will hold, right?

Comment: I meant to imply that it's wrong as you stated it in your question. I guess it's true for smooth functions, but I don't know how to prove that rigorously.